# How could I turn this PineScript input into a usable function?

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading

I have written an input variable to define what type of moving average I'd like to use in my strategy. I have a significant amount of other code in the script so I have tried to choose only what is relevant. The input variable:

```
MA1Type = input(title="MA1 Type", defval="SMA", options=["RMA", "SMA", "EMA", "WMA", "HMA", "DEMA", "TEMA", "VWMA"])
```

And the function that I'm trying to use the input for, is the "sma" function here:

```
MovAv1 = sma(close, MA1Period)
```

This is my working MA function below

```
ma(MAType, MASource, MAPeriod) =>
if MAType == "SMA"
    sma(MASource, MAPeriod)
else
    if MAType == "EMA"
        ema(MASource, MAPeriod)
    else
        if MAType == "WMA"
            wma(MASource, MAPeriod)
        else
            if MAType == "RMA"
                rma(MASource, MAPeriod)
            else
                if MAType == "HMA"
                    wma(2*wma(MASource, MAPeriod/2)-wma(MASource, MAPeriod), round(sqrt(MAPeriod)))
                else
                    if MAType == "DEMA"
                        e = ema(MASource, MAPeriod)
                        2 * e - ema(e, MAPeriod)
                    else
                        if MAType == "TEMA"
                            e = ema(MASource, MAPeriod)
                            3 * (e - ema(e, MAPeriod)) + ema(ema(e, MAPeriod), MAPeriod)
                        else
                            if MAType == "VWMA"
                                vwma(MASource, MAPeriod)
```

The error message I get, when I try to use my ma function instead of one of the built-in functions; is here:

> cannot call 'anonym_function_0' with arguments (series[float], input integer);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Soooooo...... I was calling additional arguments that counteracted the parameters I had assigned to the function. What I should have written were the arguments, of the function; that I had provided within the function declaration. For example:

```
MovAv1 = sma(close, MA1Period)
```

Should have been written as:

```
MovAv1 = (ma(MA1Type, MA1Source, MA1Period))
```

MA1Source, and MA1Period are input variables that I had made earlier in my script, and subsequently forgotten about the implications of.

Incredibly simple answer that was literally right in front of me, but I'm new to PineScript so I am easily confused.

Answer (score 0):

See the [Moving Averages, input with options sample](https://www.tradingview.com/script/P1HtHJOI-Moving-Averages-input-with-options-sample/) script.
It contains an example of what you're looking for.